# Unable to submit push notification. ErrorCode 460

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, mongoose-im

I am using MongooseIM with MongooseIM-Push feature. I have configured FCM on both Android and IOS and Its working fine for both (tested by sending Notification push from node js code).

while using the MongooseimPush (running docker image) although the I am able to receive push on android still I am getting the below error for each  stanza sent

```
11:46:00.372 [error] Unable to submit push notification. ErrorCode 460, Payload <<"{\"topic\":null,\"service\":\"fcm\",\"mode\":\"prod\",\"data\":{\"message-count\":1,\"last-message-sender\":\"a9jpmqz7sil9qdbr@localhost\",\"last-message-body\":\"{\\\"text\\\":\\\"nh\\\"}\"}}">>.Possible API mismatch - tried URL: <<"v2/notification/fdOXsUNXwHc:APA91bG2oIdmhrRZ5L3w2RCPE17sn9fur74LGYGnqHWl5p5o3Xr4Y-1YDhwjfhQAs4gLr7gOETsKDArL5wPuFXJGvoW2nrhr87DdAxvWpY0J4uh1ZuoZMTqn7w14vwg7kW48Lki9T8Xx">>.

11:46:00.383 [error] Unable to submit push notification. ErrorCode 460, Payload <<"{\"topic\":null,\"service\":\"fcm\",\"mode\":\"prod\",\"alert\":{\"title\":\"a9jpmqz7sil9qdbr@localhost\",\"tag\":\"a9jpmqz7sil9qdbr@localhost\",\"click_action\":null,\"body\":\"{\\\"text\\\":\\\"nh\\\"}\",\"badge\":1}}">>.Possible API mismatch - tried URL: <<"v2/notification/fdOXsUNXwHc:APA91bG2oIdmhrRZ5L3w2RCPE17sn9fur74LGYGnqHWl5p5o3Xr4Y-1YDhwjfhQAs4gLr7gOETsKDArL5wPuFXJGvoW2nrhr87DdAxvWpY0J4uh1ZuoZMTqn7w14vwg7kW48Lki9T8Xx">>.
```

No error in Docker

```
11:48:37.174 [debug] Sent 200 in 86ms
11:48:37.327 [debug] Sent 200 in 245ms
11:48:42.580 [debug] POST /v2/notification/dU5K-csGDQ8:APA91bH6V4ctXe_tFy8xE6jfCVLCbS4lMuEU4SlFxZqAF85Hb9I-eoZhRQCfCXSw-JenX8xJ5DYnfSDTyzdoj0JmizdRCmNnCDPecevQj3r6waoYQhRKE_xOKBNLDAQVifn7VzPDwsCX
11:48:42.582 [debug] POST /v2/notification/ffFcxJGqD7Q:APA91bHCGy6qA-i2dzjIVDxBvevo3hcCzbBXXB1JrdFclpalGwaWCdE3PAd-XtEKj9MIJxITnOA7E3l_lUkRPvQybGbGDAkH3sNBawRFekQEocxHnQxJize_BoY4I10GieYY0_4602Xd
```

Following are the config in mongooseim config file

```
   {mod_event_pusher, [
     {backends, [
       {push, [{wpool, [{workers, 100}]}]}
     ]}
   ]},
   {mod_pubsub, [
       {host, "pubsub.@HOST@"},
       {plugins, [<<"push">>]}
   ]},
   {mod_push_service_mongoosepush, [
      {pool_name, mongoose_push_http},
      {api_version, "v2"}
   ]}
{outgoing_pools, [
  {http, global, mongoose_push_http,
    [{strategy, available_worker}],
    [{server, "https://localhost:8443"}]}
]}.
```

Comment: Actually, I have installed/uninstalled the app with same username multiple times and this error is showing error for (n-1) times the app is registered against push in mongooseim-push. How to delete the old push registerd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response code *460* corresponds to invalid device token. As you said in comment you installed/uninstalled the app multiple times. It is possible that all the old tokens are no longer valid and Mongoose gets the *460* error. The notification succeeds because at least one (most probably the newest) token is valid. In order to remove previously registered tokens you can deactivate the token as described in [XEP-0357#disabling](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0357.html#disabling). I also recommend reading the [tutorial](https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/Push-notifications/) regarding Push Notifications with MongooseIM and MongoosePush [3].

The configuration you provided looks correct to me.

Comment: Thanku so much. I have 1 more doubt regarding the presence stanza in mongooseim

Comment: Please help me in above question also

Comment: I answered to the other question.